# Is closing a database opened with window.openDatabase necessary?

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

The code at the moment reads something in the order of...

```
DoAnything() {
  OpenTheDatabase()
  // ... Do all the things! ...
}
```

However, the database object is never closed. This is worrisome.

The database is opened as follows:

```
var db = window.openDatabase( ... paramters ... );
```

No `.closeDatabase` function exists, or the documentation is incomplete. I thought the following might suffice:

```
db=null;
```

I see that `sqlite3_close(sqlite3*)` and `int sqlite3_close_v2(sqlite3*)` exist, but I'm unsure how to apply them in this case.

How do I close the database, and is it necessary?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally you only have one database connection that you open on app startup, and there is no need to close it while the app is open. It's a single threaded, single user app, so a lot of the normal rules about database connections don't apply.

When the app shuts down, you can rely on the browser to close everything - given the average quality of code on the web, browsers have to be pretty good at cleanup.

Setting db to null and letting the garbage collector do its thing will probably also work, but it is better not to create the extra objects in the first place.

Comment: Fair enough.

Subsequent question then, since the metaphor of browser pages is being used, Do you know if the db connection open-ness persistent between pages? Or are we talking garbage collection between pages here?

Comment: Not sure about the internals of specific browsers, but certainly everything set up on one page should disappear when the next page is loaded. My own apps are all single page anyway - Maintaining app state is a lot harder if it gets cleared by a page change.