# Phonegap database don't work after navigator.app.exitApp()

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

I sometimes close my app programmatically with `naviagor.app.exitApp()`. I noticed that when I reopen the app my SQLite Database don't work anymore (If I close the app with the task manager there is no problem). Is there any way to close the database connection programmantically? Or is there any other way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this to close an SQLite Database.

```
database.close()
```

Comment: omg seems like this is working :D I'll try it more often before I accept this answer. Basically i trusted that thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574820/sqlite-phonegap-window-closedatabase-shouldnt-i-be-closeing-the-db-object

Comment: Hopefully it is, nothing more frustrating than looking through code over and over again unable to figure out how to fix something. If it is indeed working make sure you accept it as an answer, good luck!

Comment: Oh yes..^^ Thank you very much, now I'm sure that it is working

Comment: Same problem but the SQLite database doesn't seem to have close anymore

Comment: An SQLite Database should have a .close(), are you sure you are trying to close the right thing?